# How do you stop a StreamingHttpResponse in django when the client disconnects?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-channels

My django server serves a video feed, as a jpeg stream, one frame at a time.

It looks like this:

```
class VideoCamera():
    def __init__(self):
        # code

    def get_frame(self):
        # code
        return frame

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        yield camera.get_frame()

def view_cam(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(VideoCamera()), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
```

It's a live camera feed, so there's no end to the stream. I need it to be interrupted when the client disconnects, but so far, I can't figure out how to detect that a client disconnected.

Am I missing something?

Edit:

To eliminate anything to do with the camera, I did this:

```
def gen():
    for i in range(1000):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        yield i

def view_cam(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
```

and connected to my view with `curl -N http://localhost/my_app/view_cam/`. It streams the numbers, and when I stop curl with Ctrl+C, the generator just keeps running indefinitely, not noticing that the client disappeared. If I run and stop curl a few more times, I have multiple instances of my `gen()` function running, which is exactly what happens with the camera.

Edit 2:

This project uses Django Channels. I just noticed that if I disable channels by commenting it out in my settings.py, the above example works perfectly. I didn't think channels was related to the problem, but apparently, it is - somehow.

The channels development server does actually detect the disconnect after 10 seconds (not immediately like the default django server), and show this:

> Application instance call() running at
>   /home/pi/paperless_clipboard/venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/http.py:213>
>   wait_for=._call_check_cancel() at
>   /usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py:452, Task._wakeup()]>> for
>   connection  took too long to shut down and was killed.

but despite the message that something was killed, `gen()` keeps running, printing numbers to the terminal.

Comment: I seem to be running into issues in production when using StreamingHttpResponse with django channels. I'm seeing a runaway process that eats a ton of CPU and the last request it processed was returning a StreamingHttpResponse to the client via django channels. Did you ever get StreamingHttpResponse working with django channels? Or just decided it was the culprit and disabled django channels?

Comment: It's been a while since I was working on this, but if I recall, I never did fix this. I think I just got around it by using the channels websocket to return the camera frames instead of StreamingHttpResponse()

Comment: Hi @John canyou share a sample of how you used opencv to return the frames instead of StreamingHttpResponse()?

Answer (score 1):

You can't according the docs:

> **Performance considerations**
>   Django is designed for short-lived requests. Streaming responses will **tie a worker process for the entire duration of the response**. This may result in poor performance.
>
> Generally speaking, you should perform expensive tasks outside of the request-response cycle, rather than resorting to a streamed response.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine without `django channels` enabled. The Streaming response gets interrupted, and the class' `__del__` method gets run, which is exactly what I was hoping for. I'm just not sure why it doesn't work with `channels` enabled